# How do I wake up a specific thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a bunch of threads blocked waiting for a message. Each message has an ID which points to a specific thread. I have the following implementations:

1) All threads are waiting on the same lock object using `Monitor.Wait`. When a message comes in, I call `Monitor.PulseAll` and each thread checks its own ID with the message ID. If there is a match, thread continues. Otherwise it waits again on the same object. With this approach, every message arrival causes N-1 threads to wake up and mismatch the ID and go back to sleep.

2) Each thread creates a `ManualResetEvent` and add it to a dictionary. The dictionary maps message id to its event. When the message arrives, it calls `map[message.Id].Set()` which wakes up the specific thread.

3) This last implementation is very similar to #2, except it uses a lock object instead of `ManualResetEvent`. The hypothesis is that `ManualResetEvent` is an expensive object. This approach is more complex if compared to `ManualResetEvent`.

What's the best approach here? Is there a better one?

Comment: Code them out and run the performance test on your actual data to see which work better in your particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

The question description is fairly vague, so it's hard to know for sure what your best approach would be. That said…

I would not use #1 or #2 at all. #1 requires waking *every* thread up just so *one* thread can run, which is obviously inefficient, and #2 uses the unmanaged Windows-based synchronization objects, which is not as efficient as using a built-in .NET mechanism.

Your #3 option is on the face of it not unreasonable given the problem description. However, IMHO you should not be reimplementing this yourself. I.e. as near as I can tell, you (for some reason) have messages that need to be provided to specific threads, i.e. a given message must be processed only by one specific thread.

In this case, I think you should just create a separate message queue for each thread, and add the message to the appropriate queue. There are lots of ways to implement the queue, but the most obvious for this particular example seems to me to be to use `BlockingCollection<T>`. By default, this uses a queue as the underlying collection data structure. The other feature that's important here is the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` method, which allows you to write a `foreach` loop in the dependent thread to retrieve messages as they are queued. The loop will block when no message is available, waiting for one to be provided via some other thread.

You can use a dictionary to map message ID to the appropriate queue for each thread.

Note that this not really IMHO a performance issue. It's more about using an appropriate data structure for the given problem. I.e. you seem to have a queue of messages, where you want to dispatch each message to a different thread depending on its ID. Instead, I think you should implement multiple queues of messages, one for each thread, and then use the existing .NET features to implement your logic so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Note also that if you still must maintain a single input queue for the messages (e.g. because that's the interface presented to some other component in your program), you can and should still do the above. You'll just have some adapter code that dequeues a message from the main, single message queue and routes to the appropriate thread-specific queue.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. I wanted to make it kind of generic. But you got option #2 wrong: each thread has its own ManualResetEvent. So when response arrives, a single thread wakes up.

I have a non-fixed number of threads. I think a BlockingQueue for each of  them is overkill.

I just came across ManualResetEventSlim. That's what I used.

Comment: @Gatis: I never said option #2 involved waking multiple threads. That said, your other issue with options #2 and #3 is that two or more messages could be queue before any of the consuming threads actually get to run, so they need a mechanism to determine which queued message is actually the one they need to process. I.e. you effectively have to write the logic in `BlockingCollection<T>` anyway, so you might as well use that.

Answer (score 0):

1. To **wake up** a specific thread or to even **start** a thread - [`Thread.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. To check if your thread hasn't **aborted** yet - [`Thread.IsAlive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Thread.IsAlive(v=VS.110).aspx) property.
3. To check if a thread is **running** - [`Thread.ThreadState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use the above three props and methods to have desired control over the threads and manage them at a very fine granularity.

When you are initializing the threads, put them all in a `Dictionary<ID, Thread>()`. Now, whenever you get a message, simply get the thread with required ID and wake it up.

Comment: That's what I did in #2 and #3. The question is what to use to make thread sleep/wake up. I used ManualResetEvent and it works. My question is now whether there is a better per-thread mechanism.

Comment: I think we're talking about different things. I already have multiple threads started...

Comment: @Gatis: I thought you would think that. Thread.Start() is not just for starting, but for waking threads as well.

Comment: Did you mean Suspend/Resume? They are obsolete: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tttdef8x(v=vs.110).aspx